# remove duplicated rows and convert it to list or tuple

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe as follows (Name is index):

| Name | Age | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 20 | 2020 |
| Tom | 20 | 2021 |
| Nick | 19 | 2019 |
| Jack | 18 | 2018 |

my goal is to remove duplicate and convert the column year to tuple or list, like below

| Name | Age | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 20 | (2020, 2019) |
| Nick | 19 | 2019 |
| Jack | 18 | 2018 |

how can I do that efficiently since my df has more than 800,000 rows

Comment: What have you tried to this end?

Comment: Also your expected output is mysterious for `iat[0, -1]`

Comment: You sure you want to do this? You'll lose out on the benefits of vectorization for any processing you're planning to do on the year column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.unique` on `groupby`. Assuming `Name` is already the index:

```
>>> df.groupby(level=0).agg(np.unique)
      Age          year
Name                   
Jack   18          2018
Nick   19          2019
Tom    20  [2020, 2021]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a `groupby` + `agg(np.array)`?

```
>>> df.groupby(['Name', 'Age'], as_index=False)['year'].agg(np.array)
   Name  Age          year
0  Jack   18          2018
1  Nick   19          2019
2   Tom   20  [2020, 2021]
```

If you don't care about the items being strings, you can do this:

```
>>> df.assign(year=df['year'].astype(str)).groupby(['Name', 'Age'], as_index=False, sort=False)['year'].agg(list).pipe(lambda x: x.assign(year=x['year'].str.join(', ')))
   Name  Age        year
0   Tom   20  2020, 2021
1  Nick   19        2019
2  Jack   18        2018
```

Comment: they same Name is index so it'll disappear in the output

Comment: Why use `['year']` only?

Comment: Because that's all the OP demoed, but you're answer is better. +1 soon :)

Comment: @Corralien column year is the only one that is not duplicate, other columns are all having unique rows

Comment: @richardec I am getting ValueError, I used np.unique from Corralien answer and it worked

Comment: @Sam.H Okay, that's fine. Corralien's is very good - you _should_ accept it. I also will upvote it tomorrow when my limit is reset :)